# How do generic types fit into the type hierarchy?

Tags: generics, kotlin, types

Kotlin has a complete and elegant type hierarchy – if that is the right word, since it is a directed acyclic graph rather than a tree – described with diagrams at http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000818.html and https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/the-beauty-of-kotlin-typing-system-7a2804fe6cf0

What I'm not clear about is how generics fit into all this.

How do generic types like `List` and `Map`, and specializations thereof like `List<Int>` and `Map<String, Int>` fit into the type hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` and `Map` are not types; they're classes.  To form a type, you need to specify the necessary type parameters, e.g. `List<Int>` (or a [type projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) such as `List<*>`).

(This is different from Java, which allows [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), mainly for backward compatibility.)

The type relationships depend upon the [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance): for example, `List<Int>` is a subtype of `List<Number>`, because it's covariant in its type parameter; but `MutableList<Int>` is invariant and has no relationship with `MutableList<Number>` (except that they're both subtypes of `Any`).

This adds extra dimensions to the type hierarchy, making it rather more complex than the simple graph you may have seen.  But the principle's straightforward enough, so it's not usually drawn in.

More details, as ever, in the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/generics.html).